# User Profile Import from Different environment

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, fim

I just wondering if there is a way to import User profile from different environment. For instance copy the user profile import from Production environment to PreProd environment. Both environment using the same domain. Why we want to do this is fast track the process. Since we have 4 synchronisation connection therefore the Full Sync process can take up 3 weeks to complete.

Thank you